# Is the topology of the p-adic valuation to the unramfied extension complete?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory, class-field-theory

> Consider $\mathbb Q_p^{\text{ur}}$ the maximal unramified extension of the p-adic numbers. Suppose that on $\mathbb Q_p$ we have the usual absolute value that extends $|\frac{a}{b}|_p=\frac{1}{p^{v_p(a)-v_p(b)}}$ to $\mathbb Q_p$. Now it is known that $|\cdot|_p$ extends uniquely to $\mathbb Q_p^{\text{ur}}$. Is $\mathbb Q_p^{\text{ur}}$ a complete space with respect to this absolute value?

I used notations and definitions as in [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf) (pages 105-124).

My question is motivated by my attempt to find a a non-archimedean complete and discretely valued field, whose residue field is algebraically closed and I believe that $\mathbb Q_p^{\text{ur}}$ is a good candidate.

The other candidate that I tried was $\mathbb Q_p^{\text{al}}$, which has an algebraically closed residue field, but does not work for two reasons:
First, the extension of $|\cdot|_p$ is not discrete w.r.t. $\mathbb Q_p^{\text{al}}$. Second, $\mathbb Q_p^{\text{al}}$ is not complete with respect to the extended absolute value.

Now, on the other hand,  $\mathbb Q_p^{\text{ur}}$  has an algebraically closed residue field and as it is explained by Lubin [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185245/is-the-topology-of-the-p-adic-valuation-to-the-unramfied-extension-discrete), it is also discretely valued. Now the only thing left to check is whether it is complete, but I am stuck here.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927760/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. $ \mathbf Q_p^{\textrm {unr}} $ has countable degree over $ \mathbf Q_p $, and it is a well-known fact that there are no Banach spaces of countable dimension over the ground field. (Hint: Baire category theorem.)

For your attempts, have you considered the field $ \mathbf C((T)) $?

Comment: Thank you very much ! And in fact, I also believe the example that I tried can be fixed, if I replace the $\mathbb Q_p^{\text{ur}}$ by its completion instead.

Answer (score 4):

It’s easy to see concretely that the maximal unramified extension is not complete:

Let $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\zeta_3,\cdots$ be a sequence of integral elements in larger and larger unramified extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$. Like, for instance, $\zeta_m=$ primitive $(p^m-1)$-th root of unity. Then just write down the Cauchy series $Z=\sum_mp^m\zeta_m$. Obviously not in the maximal unramified exension, because that is an algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q_p$, and every element generates a finite extension. But $Z$ is not in any finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$.